# JPA (Hibernate) table initialization, good practice

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, persistence

The thing is that I'm not sure if using Hibernate for first table initialization (creating tables) is a good approach. 
I want to have absolutely control on this process.

So, I thought about using DDL initialization scripts. But it seems that it will be DBMS-dependent, it is bad too.

I want to have full control on initialization process and at the same time it should be DBMS-independent.

How can I reach this goals?

Comment: Have you seen Liquibase? http://liquibase.org/

Comment: No, I haven't. It looks interesting :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to use the DB for.  You can set up two config files, say for example one for testing that would create the tables in derby, and then a production config file that would use a 'production' database where tables are assumed to exist.

Also, it makes sense to have tables be created while in development so that you can create objects/tables on the fly, but once you go to release you can switch configuration.

Comment: But what if I want to have opportunity to initialize my tables in production. For example, during first-execution of some web-based application.

Comment: Generally it is a bad idea to use auto table creation for production.  Usually you should have tested well enough to know exactly what schema you need for production and then pre-install the DB so that you don't ever affect production data.  Although if your app is not data-intensive/sensitive then it could work fine. In my experience the App should not have any kind of control over the DB.  Separation of concerns.  If the app fails it should be isolated from adversely affecting the data.